# How To Find The Caret Position In A TextBox Using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, position, caret

I have some `TextBox`, `MultiLine TextBox`, `RichTextBox` in my `WindowsFormApps` using *Visual Studio 2015*. Now I want to let my user type text in these fields and along with I want to know the `Caret Pointer` position (X-Axis,Y-Axis) continuously whether my user type text in the end of text or in start of the text or any where in the middle of the text.

[image]

Can I get the correct position (X-Axis,Y-Axis) at Run Time continuously in some class level variables to use it on other places...???

### **CODE ADDED:**

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace DEMO_Apps
    {
        public partial class MainForm : Form
        {
            int xpos;
            int ypos;
            public MainForm()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var o = Utility.GetCaretPoint(textBox1);
                xpos = o.X;
                ypos = o.Y;
                textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(xpos + "," +  ypos);                
            }     
        }

        public static class Utility
        {
            ///for System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
            public static System.Drawing.Point GetCaretPoint(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox)
            {
                return textBox.GetPositionFromCharIndex(textBox.SelectionStart);
            }

            ///for System.Windows.Controls.TextBox
            public static System.Windows.Point GetCaretPoint(System.Windows.Controls.TextBox textBox)
            {
                return textBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(textBox.SelectionStart).Location;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your edited question, I checked the code and found that when caret is at last character, the function gives empty position so I changed a bit, the following Functions should give you what you want:

```
 namespace DEMO_Apps
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        int xpos;
        int ypos;
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var o = Utility.GetCaretPoint(textBox1);
            xpos = o.X;
            ypos = o.Y;
            textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(xpos + "," +  ypos);                
        }     
    }

    public static class Utility
    {
        ///for System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
        public static System.Drawing.Point GetCaretPoint(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox)
        {
            int start = textBox.SelectionStart;
            if (start == textBox.TextLength)
            start --;

            return textBox.GetPositionFromCharIndex(start);
        }

        ///for System.Windows.Controls.TextBox requires reference to the following dlls: PresentationFramework, PresentationCore & WindowBase.
        //So if not using those dlls you should comment the code below:

        public static System.Windows.Point GetCaretPoint(System.Windows.Controls.TextBox textBox)
        {
            return textBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(textBox.SelectionStart).Location;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how to use it and how to get both (X-Axis,Y-Axis) in two different class level variables...???

Comment: @MuhammadHassan based on your comment I edited my answer. If it solves your problem, please accept it to close the question

Comment: Getting error at `System.Windows.Point`  and `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox`. Rest the `///for System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` giving `0,0` points.

Comment: Can you post your code do that I can see why you get error.

Comment: You can see the code now. I want to get the Caret Position (X-Axis,Y-Axis)  with respect to `textbox1` borders of `textbox1` in `textbox2` while user change (add/delete) text inside `textbox1`...

Comment: @MuhammadHassan check my improved answer.

Comment: Perfect. That's it what I want. Thanks a lot... :-)

Comment: Tip: And if we use `Point locationOnForm = textBox1.FindForm().PointToClient(  textBox1.Parent.PointToScreen(textBox1.Location));` then we can get our `textBox1` location w.r.t parent form and then can add it with your code to get the CARET axis w.r.t form. :)

Comment: Downvoted accepted answer without even explanation? Please provide comments as to why it is worth downvoting

Comment: @MuhammadHassan I know you voted up because you accepted an answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`.SelectionStart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart(v=vs.110).aspx) property of TextBox to get the Position of the caret.

```
int positionOfcarett = txtSample.SelectionStart;
```

Let the Text in the TextBox `txtSample` be `ABCD` and the caret is currently in between `B` and `C` the above code will give you  `positionOfcarett =2`;

**Updates as per comment:**

If you want to get the mouse position over the Textbox you need to use `TextBox1_MouseMove` event From that you will get the X-axis values and Y-axis values as well.

```
 int xpos = e.X;
 int ypos = e.Y;
```

If you want to get it reference to the Form then use `Form__MouseMove`

Comment: Sorry I don't get you, What you mean by x-axis and y-axis inside a textbox?

Comment: I got the caret position of a blinking bar now I want to find out its position like mouse pointer position having (X-Axis,Y-Axis) with respect to whole win form...???

Comment: for that you should use `TextBox1_MouseMove` event of the textbox

Comment: So will it reply with mouse cursor position(X-Axis,Y-Axis) or caret position(X-Axis,Y-Axis)...???

Comment: @MuhammadHassan: well then you can use the first option. And use it inside the Click event of the Textbox